# how to solve the "zlibinstream:exceeded bytesIn" error in vnc

Tags: vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer, svn-client

Every now and then I get the "zlibinstream:exceeded bytesIn" error when trying to connect to my server through my vnc. Why do I get this error and how can I solve it when I get it - without restarting my server ?

Answer (score 18):

Came across the same issue a couple of times. I am not aware of permanent fix, but for a quick one just change colour to Fullcolour.

For me in VNC Viewer it was in options/Expert/FullColour to true.

Comment: Turning FullColour to true fixed it for me too. As a test, I tried turning FullColour back to false and the problem came back. Strange that this problem just started today after 1.5 years of exactly the same usage.

Comment: Ack, maybe not. The problem just came back (22 days later) and FullColour is still true.

Comment: While I can't definitively say this is the cause, we have just upgraded Cisco AnyConnect VPN client from 3.x to 4.1.08005 and I am noticing this error for the first time. As you say, changing the colour settings seems to have made it go away for now. thanks

Comment: funnily changing FullColour to "False" did it for me. So I'm not really sure, if this has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 5):

## **Another quick fix (for Mac):**

Reading the other responses and trying out a few, I feel toggling random Properties/Options will "solve" this problem. Do the following for Real VNC on Mac:

Options -> Picture Quality -> High. Then Set it back to Automatic.

Comment: saved my day! Not sure, why there is no real fix for this issue yet!

Comment: I made this fix on the fly and viewer is back. Let see if works permanently!

Answer (score 4):

In my case the solutions is just to change quality to `Low`. Seems to work fine.

Comment: This worked for me, did you ever find a more permanent fix? I'd rather the picture quality not stay low...Edit: Actually, I changed it back to high or automatic or anything, it seems to still work. How strange.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to turn off "`Adapt to network speed (recommended)`" (under `Options->Display`) and then move the compression slider to the left from "`All available colors, medium compression`" to "`Hundreds of colors`".

Prior to this, Burpy Burp's answer of changing options/Expert/FullColour to true temporarily fixed the problem but it came back 22 days later.

Comment: Even this failed eventually. I had to change it back from "Hundreds of colors" to "All available colors, max compression". It seems like every once in a while it's necessary to force a mode change in order to work around this issue. The start/end mode is unimportant.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be related with timing. On my mac, I'm having the same issue and usually waiting for a while and retrying is the only thing that works for me. It always comes back but not an immediate solution.

Answer (score 2):

Color level Full didnt resolve the issue but when set Options-Picture Quality High instead of Automatic resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the googlers out there that find this question: Changing the "prefered encoding" to something other than "ZRLE" (I used "hextile")is what solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the options dialog without changing anything did it for me. **Baffled**.